# Media Queries not functioning as expected when uploaded on live server

Tags: css, media-queries

I made a Netflix clone and I was working on making it responsive. It was working fine and giving the desired output in VS Code but then I uploaded it to a live website to check if it is working then, but the responsiveness was no longer working as expected.

Below is the media queries code >>>>

```
@media screen and (max-width:768px) {
   .logobtn img{
        height: 30px;
   }
   img.dropdown{
    height: 10px;
    width: 15px;
   }
   .btn:nth-child(1){
    margin-right: 10px;
   }
   .content{
    /* padding: 0px; */
    width: 330px;
    margin-left: -20px;
   }
   .content h1{
    font-size: 30px;
    line-height: 37px;
    padding: 0;
   }
   .content h3{
    padding: 0;
    width: 375px;
    font-size: 24px;
   }
   .form{
    flex-direction: column;
    position: relative;
    height: 40px;

   }
   .email{
    margin-left: -155px;
    /* margin-right: -100px; */
    padding-right: 0px;
   }
   .submit{
    position: absolute;top: 50px;
    /* border-radius: 10px; */
   }
   .row{
    flex-direction: column;
   }
 
}
```

Comment: We need to see your HTML as well. Please read [ask] and update your question with a [mre] of your code.

Comment: Sounds like cache issue or stylesheet override, either way, we don't have enough of debugging details.

Comment: Start with refreshing your page using CTRL + SHIFT + R, and checking your console for errors